# Can SELinux filter system calls?

Tags: linux, selinux

Let's say I want to restrict use of the system call `shutdown` to `/sbin/mount` or filter the arguments that get passed to the system call `mount`. Can SELinux policy be used to achieve this?

Comment: Your objective is unclear.  No one would like to prevent their system from ever being shut down, even if it is possible to stop different programs from doing it.

Comment: You may be interesd in the [seccomp filter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/prctl/seccomp_filter.txt) framework.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I am currently interested in the ways embedded platforms and consumer electronic devices are locked down. I think SELinux can be used to allow only certain executables to call executables like `mount`, `shutdown`, and so forth, but that can be defeated if a non-system executable just uses the system calls directly.

Comment: @larsks From that page: "System call filtering isn't a sandbox.  It provides a clearly defined mechanism for minimizing the exposed kernel surface.  It is meant to be a tool for sandbox developers to use.  Beyond that, policy for logical behavior and information flow should be managed with a combination of other system hardening techniques and, potentially, an LSM of your choosing.".

Comment: @Melab Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 2):

use SECCOMP to block syscalls. if you are on rhel8 or a linux distro using systemd you can use it to restrict  syscalls that a process can use